# Shopware 6, how to add custom logo to theme.json when creating new plugin?

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

I tried to do it with this url **app/storefront/src/assets/logo.svg** but it didn't work
and then I tried this url **app/storefront/public/bundles/logo.svg** and **app/storefront/dist/assets/logo.svg** and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FpGk.jpg) tried to do it with official doc, but it still didn't work.

The parent theme used this URL **app/storefront/dist/assets/logo/demostore-logo.png** but it didn't work with the custom plugin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.